# How to fix an error expected expression in c when you haven't gotten anything missing or out of place?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, cs50

I try running a programming line in c where I'm supposed to define a variable of char* (used later on for a comparison with type char*) and setting it equal to the letter extracted from a word variable `

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
char* ALPHABETS[26] ={"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
int POINTS[26] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int compute_score(string word){
    int totalScore = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<strlen(word);i++){
        for(int j=0; j<26;j++){
            char* letterExtract =char* isupper(word[i]);
            if( letterExtract == ALPHABETS[j]){
                totalScore = totalScore + POINTS[j];
            }
```

more specifically the line:

```
char* letterExtract =char* isupper(word[i]);
```

gives me an error which says:[image which says error: expected expression:char* letterExtract =char* isupper(word[i]);(with a little ^ below the c after the = sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNgVt.png)
How do I fix it?

I tried removing the char* after the = symbol, however this generates an incompatible integer to pointer conversion error

Comment: Of course, `isupper` returns an int containing the upper case value for the letter you provided to. How would you want to assign that to a `char*`? By the way, you shouldn't `toupper` again and again within the loop, store the result in a variable before entering.

Comment: It appears pretty meaningless to store single characters as C-strings. Makes your whole character handling needlessly complicated. Prefer ordinary characters: `char alphabet[] = { 'A', 'B', ... , 'Z' };` – and if the terminating null character doesn't disturb you you can even have `char alphabet[] = "ABC...Z";`

Comment: And you shouldn't use all-upper-case names for variables. Usual convention is to reserve such identifiers for *macros*.

Comment: @Aconcagua "isupper returns an int containing the upper case value " --> No.  (I got caught too.)  OP wants `toupper()`.  At least a dozen short-comings to OP's code.

Comment: Look at how you're calling `strlen`, and then look at how you're attempting to call `isupper`.  Notice a difference?

Comment: All this can be so much simpler: `char const* alphabet = "ABC..."; for(... word ...) { char const* pos = strchr(alphabet, toupper((unsigned char)word[i]); if(pos) { score += points[pos - alphabet]; } }`

Comment: `strlen` within the loop condition isn't a good idea either, you calculate again and again. You could instead have: `for(int i = 0, e = strlen(word); i < e; ++i)`

Comment: OK, the sleeping one seems having been woken up (thanks, chux…). Truth is: `isupper` indeed returns an int – and that one contains a boolean value indicating if the character already *is* upper. Still question remains: how would you want t assign to a pointer? Apart from that's not what you want, you want to convert to upper case instead, which is to be done via `toupper`. Note the difference in the first two characters of the function name – which admittedly I missed as well at first ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are quite some more issues with your code that the single line you highlighted…

Lets start right at top:

```
char* ALPHABETS[26] = {"A","B", /* ... , */ "Z"};
int POINTS[26] = {1, 3, /* ... , */ 10};
```

At first all capital identifiers usually are used to identify *macros*, it is not a good idea to violate this convention for variables. Then you try to maintain a list of single characters, but you store them in C-strings. This makes your character processing needlessly complicated and prevents usage of standard library functions. Additionally: You assign string literals to `char*` pointers. While actually legal it is *not* a good idea to do so, you risk accidental modification of the literals later on, which yields undefined behaviour. Whenever string literals are involved, assign them to `char const*` pointers only.

Back to storage as strings: Store the characters as what they are, characters:

```
char alphabet[] = { 'A', 'B', /* ... ,*/ 'Z' };
//            ^ with initializer, size can be deduced, you don't need to specify
```

or even simpler, you can use a string literal to initialise an array of `char`:

```
char alphabet[] = "ABC...Z";
```

Note, though, that the array will then be larger by one to include the terminating null character. In given case it's not an issue, though. Note, too: *Now* you *can* have a non-const array, the string literal is copied. In your case a simple single pointer would suffice as well:

```
char const* alphabet = "ABC...Z";
//   ^^^^^ now again: pointing to a literal!
```

Then you repeatedly call library functions for one and the same data:

```
for (int i=0;i<strlen(word);i++)
               ^^^^^^
    for(int j=0; j<26;j++)
        char* letterExtract =char* isupper(word[i]);
                                   ^^^^^^^
```

You might hope on the compiler being able to optimise that, but with some view minor changes you can achieve that on your own:

for (int i = 0, end = strlen(word); i < end; ++i)
{
char* letterExtract = char* isupper(word[i]);
for(int j=0; j<26;j++)

Then coming finally to the line you discovered yourself not to be correct:

```
char* letterExtract = char* isupper(word[i]);
```

At very first you seem to try to cast the result to another type – for doing so, you need to enclose the type to be casted to in parentheses:

```
char* letterExtract = (char*)isupper(word[i]);
```

While that now would cast and allow the assignment, it would still fail miserably in doing what you actually want it to do: `isupper` returns an `int` indicating if the character is upper case or not, the result is either 0 or 1, and its meaningless to assign these to a pointer (in given context; using 0 for a null pointer, for instance, is fine, we have different semantics here).

What you actually want, though, is the upper case letter directly to be able to look it up in the `alphabet` array. For this purpose your friend is `toupper` instead, it returns a value encoding the upper case letter, and you might want to store it as such:

```
char upper = toupper(word[i]);
```

A more advanced issue still is left here: if `char` is signed or unsigned is implementation defined, and with signed `char` a value residing in the upper half of the (single) character range (i.e. within [128;255]) we actually have a negative value, provoking `toupper` to fail. So correct usage is casting to unsigned char first:

```
char upper = toupper((unsigned char)word[i]);
```

This is the final version you should use.

Next issue is a *magic number* within your code:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
                   ^^
```

As long as using the Latin alphabet only this is unlikely to change. But what happens if you are going to include further characters, e.g. Spanish *ñ* or German 'Umlaute' (*ä*, *ö*, *ü) or maybe digits? Your `alphabet` array as well as the `points` array will change in size, and if you forget to adjust the loop you will not cover these new characters. You are robust against such changes if you deduce the length to iterate over from the array instead:

```
for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(alphabet)/sizeof(*alphabet); ++j)
```

Note, though, that this trick only works as long as you have access to the original array directly, once it has decayed to a pointer (e.g. when passing it as argument to a function) the size information is lost and the trick doesn't work any more (but you can use it to determine the size you pass to the function alongside the array itself).

Combining all these points your code finally might look like this:

```
int totalScore = 0;
for (int i = 0, end = strlen(word); i < end; ++i)
{
    char upper = toupper((unsigned char)word[i]);
    for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(alphabet)/sizeof(*alphabet); ++j)
    {
        if(alphabet[j] == upper)
        {
            totalScore += points[j];
            // no need to continue iteration, cannot match any more anyway:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Yet you still can improve it – in two different ways, mutually exclusive, though:

At first the character and the points actually are closely related, you might not want to split this information in two separate arrays you have to take care of for being of same size as well. To cover this fact you could store both values together in a struct and have an array of:

```
struct Data
{
    char character;
    int  points; 
};
struct Data data[] = { {'A', 1}, {'B', 3}, /* ... ,*/ { 'Z', 10 } };
```

And within your iterations you could have:

```
// ...
for(j)
{
    struct Data entry = data[j];
    if(data.character == upper)
    {
        totalScore += data.points;
        // ...
```

A totally different way is using a library function to find the matching character; the signature of the one in question requires a character array – which disallows combining the closely related data into a struct as above.

Having to keep the two separate arrays I'd at least align data properly to achieve better maintainability:

```
char alphabet[] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', /* ... , */ 'Z' };
int points[]    = {  1 ,  3 ,  3 , /* ... , */ 10  };
```

together with the code using `strchr`:

```
int totalScore = 0;
for (int i = 0, end = strlen(word); i < end; ++i)
{
    char const* position = strchr(alphabet, toupper((unsigned char)word[i]);
    if(position) // found at all?
    {
        totalScore += points[position - alphabet];
    }
}
```

This final one is my personal favourite ;)